# Cannot restore Electrum wallet from seedphrase

Tags: wallets, wallet-transfer

Please be gentle as I'm new here (and n00b in blockchain world).

I created an Ethereum wallet a few years ago and was under the impression that I would be able to restore my wallet on a new PC using *only my passphrase*.

I've downloaded Electrum now and selected "I already have a seed passphrase" and seemingly "restored my wallet". However I cannot see my ethers in any of the addresses in the wallet.

Am I misinterpreting some of the concepts? Am I missing some important step?

Any guidance would be more than kindly appreciated!

Comment: Were you using just a seed phrase (usually 12 or 24 words long), or a seed phrase _and_ a passphrase (sometimes called 25th word, though this is technically not accurate)?

Comment: I also have a "secret word" or "passphrase" yes. But I'm just looking to restore my wallet first from seed phrase and see my ethers in the wallet. According to some "Crypto Daddy" on Youtube this should work but I tried Electrum on my phone and entered the seedphrase but no funds appeared... Also tried Mist on my pc but that gave an error about get client or something :/

Comment: If Electrum uses the passphrase as BIP39 passphrase, you need to use the same passphrase again, as using a different passphrase will result in different addresses.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure if it does... I also have some backup `UTC-[long-filename]` file that contains my address in JSON format and some cryptographic parameters. Should this give the same results as a _proper_ seed phrase?

Comment: The keystore (UTC) file contains a single encrypted private key, depending on how it was generated it should give you access to one of the addresses derived from your seed phrase. It's worth to give it a try.